# (PHP) Live output proc_open

Tags: php, exec, proc-open, passthru

i have tried many time by using `flush()` to make the script work synchronously, the script prints only data of the first command "gcloud compute ssh yellow" and "ls -la", I am looking to make the script prints the output on every executed `fputs()`.

```
<?php

$descr = array( 0 => array('pipe','r',),1 => array('pipe','w',),2 => array('pipe','w',),);
$pipes = array();
$process = proc_open("gcloud compute ssh yellow", $descr, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    sleep(2);
    $commands = ["ls -la", "cd /home", "ls", "sudo ifconfig", "ls -l"];     
    foreach ($commands as $command) {    
        fputs($pipes[0], $command . " \n");
        while ($f = fgets($pipes[1])) {
            echo $f;
        }
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);  
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    while ($f = fgets($pipes[2])) {
        echo "\n\n## ==>> ";
        echo $f;
    }
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the loop you have waiting for input. `fgets` will only return false if it encounters EOF. Otherwise it returns the line that it read; because the linefeed is included, it doesn't return anything that can be typecast to false. You can use `stream_get_line()` instead, which does not return the EOL character. Note this would still require your command to return an **empty line** after its output so it can evaluate to false and break the while loop.

```
<?php
$prog     = "gcloud compute ssh yellow";
$commands = ["ls -la", "cd /home", "ls", "sudo ifconfig", "ls -l"];
$descr    = [0 => ['pipe','r'], 1 => ['pipe','w'], 2 =>['pipe','w']];
$pipes    = [];
$process  = proc_open($prog, $descr, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    sleep(2);
    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        fputs($pipes[0], $command . PHP_EOL);
        while ($f = stream_get_line($pipes[1], 256)) {
            echo $f . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
}
```

Another option would be to gather the output outside the loop, although this would require you to parse the output if you need to know what output came from what command.

```
<?php
$prog     = "gcloud compute ssh yellow";
$commands = ["ls -la", "cd /home", "ls", "sudo ifconfig", "ls -l"];
$descr    = [0 => ['pipe','r'], 1 => ['pipe','w'], 2 =>['pipe','w']];
$pipes    = [];
$process  = proc_open($prog, $descr, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    sleep(2);
    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        fputs($pipes[0], $command . PHP_EOL);
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $return = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
}
```

Comment: The first code still doesn't print the full output of the other commands, the last one prints the full output and works perfectly,  My goal is to make it live output with no issues. thank you Mr Miken32

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `shell_exec` with a `out.log`, with my Wordpress plugin, in admin and to show the last line in other AJAX function.

You can go see my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Jerl92/McPlayer/blob/master/admin/partials/McPlayer-admin-bulk-add-album.php) to see what it looks like, on line 516 of function `my_url()` on this file, and `my_dl()` will update the result `div`.

This is a way to do a long `shell_exec` command and this will update the output area.

The thing is to do `shell_exec()` with `2>&1 &` at the end to save the output in text file.

```
    $cmd = "youtube-dl -o '$path_implode%(id)s.%(ext)s' -f best --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-avconv --write-info-json -k " . $url;
    $res = shell_exec(''.$cmd.' > '.$path_implode.'out.log 2>&1 &');
```

And with a AJAX function in loop with setTimeout() get the file contents and split line by line.

```
    $html = file_get_contents($path_implode.'out.log');
    $res[0] = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $html);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please include the relevant code inline so it will continue to be available if you change your repo, e.g. at the moment line 516 isn't relevant to your description.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).